# Setting Textview text From static inner class

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I have two textview. when i click on them they show DateDialogBox.. this runs perfect for me.. I want to set my textview text the selected date..

```
public class ApplyLeaveFrag extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apply_leave_fragment, container,
                false);

        TextView FROM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView TO = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        // I register setOnClickListener() on both of them:

        FROM.setOnClickListener(this);
        TO.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.textView1:
            ShowCal();
            break;

        case R.id.textView2:
            ShowCal();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void ShowCal() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), this, year, month,
                    day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
                        //how can I set From or To's text From here..or any alternative

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare textview as a static class variable and use the same in onDateSet

Comment: yeah.. why didnt I think of it bfr.. :P.. noob me.. Bt i still have a prob.. I have made the changes u hav mentioned.. there are two textview's which can  call datepickerdialog .so how will i know which 1 should I update..  for eg,I cant simply write
 FROM.setText("" + String.valueOf(day) + " / " + String.valueOf(month+1) + " / " + String.valueOf(year)) ;

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: you can use a boolean value for that

Comment: m sry m new in this, like born yesterday.. can u pls mention how can I do that..

Comment: why to implement a `Fragment` as a static class and not the proper way? Statically "holding" Views is in general a bad implementation

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html. @10s scroll down and check static part of the topic in the link

Comment: @10s also check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public class ApplyLeaveFrag extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

  static TextView FROM,TO;
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apply_leave_fragment, container,
        false); 
  FROM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  TO = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
  ....
  }
  ...
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    FROM.setText("from");
    TO.setText("TO");           

  }  
  }
```

Edit: for the question in comment

Declare a static boolean class variable

```
     static boolean check=true;
```

On click

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.textView1:
        ShowCal();
        check=true;
        break;

    case R.id.textView2:
        ShowCal();
        check=false; 
        break;
    }
}
```

then

```
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        if(check==true)
        {
          // set from text
        }
        else if(check ==false)
        {
          // set to text
        } 
    }
```

Comment: wont this code would set text for both the textview, evn if m calling for only one of them..

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the job!

```
public class ApplyLeaveFrag extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

static TextView FROM;
static TextView TO;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apply_leave_fragment, container,
                false);

        FROM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TO = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        // I register setOnClickListener() on both of them:

        FROM.setOnClickListener(this);
        TO.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.textView1:
            ShowCal();
            break;

        case R.id.textView2:
            ShowCal();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void ShowCal() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), this, year, month,
                    day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
                        //how can I set From or To's text From here..or any alternative
               TO.setText("Date = " + year + "/" + "month"); // and so on

        }
    }
}
```